# jBPM6 trying to use previously completed Process Instance Id

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

Environment : `jBPM 6.0.1.Final, JBOSS EAP 6.2.0, JDK 7`
I'm using RuntimeManager of per process instance as follows

```
RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newPerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager(runtimeEnvironment, identifier);
```

And Starting the process instance with the following piece of code

```
public long startProcessWithInitialParametersAndFireBusinessRules(String processName, Map<String, Object> parameterMap) {
        RuntimeEngine runtimeEngine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(ProcessInstanceIdContext.get()); 
        KieSession ksession = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess(processName, parameterMap);
        long processInstanceId = processInstance.getId();
        ksession.fireAllRules();
        return processInstanceId;
    }
```

This configuration works well the day i configured. The very next day i tried to create new instance of my process using the application. The application throws Exception and process not instantiated. Following is the stacktrace of it.

```
(http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Error is handled by Leave approver :: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'tester']' was unable to execution operation 'Start' on task id 142 due to a no 'current status' match
    at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.evalCommand(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:128) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.taskOperation(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:318) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.task.identity.UserGroupLifeCycleManagerDecorator.taskOperation(UserGroupLifeCycleManagerDecorator.java:46) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
    at or
```

**With the same Process Instance id, Yesterday created process and was completed.
That same process instance id is trying to use by `jBPM6` today when trying to instantiate new process and due to it's status `Completed` not matching, so it throwed `Exception`.**

Why it is trying to use the `Completed` Task's Process instance id or Previously created process instance id and how can i change it's behaviour ?

**As per my observation, it is happening due to new process creation
time, it is picking up old process instance id and returning that Task
record.**

Please help to solve this problem. I tried googling, but couldn't find proper documentation of it.

**Update:**
[Click Here](https://01560387606790037290.googlegroups.com/attach/352f55a143df489a/JBPM6Runtime.java?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrEz0qDgjn0WPpFmZr4JFqfNzmyJdyCmfbzD4GhW8rQJhbiyZWgU1q261KxG3TBsV5yqffH590VifiNaz0kDRc0Ac-QASmbRh2yTdzn4usiZhSlJft4)

Java file to start Process, submit task, and terminate task all are done in the above file.
Please check it for more clarity.